# Use all your language's keywords, ideally minimally

Tags: code-challenge

- Your program must contain all your language's keywords. Ideally, you should have each one exactly once (see Scoring). Of course, this means your language must actually have keywords, so esoteric languages are probably excluded, but just in case...
- Any language used must have a dedicated Wikipedia article created more than one month ago.
- The keywords in your program must be lexed as keywords and parsed as keyword statements or expressions (i.e. no containing them within strings or comments).

A "keyword" is defined according to the language's specification or documentation if it has no specification, and must additionally have a defined purpose within the language (Java programmers need not include `goto` and `const`). Your language might distinguish "keywords" from "reserved identifiers" or something similar; only those lexemes designated as keywords are required.

## Scoring

So as not to punish languages with more keywords, your score is

`l - k + 3r`

Where l is the length of your program in bytes, k is the combined length of all the keywords you used, and r is the combined length of any keywords that occurred more than once. So if your language has only one keyword, `for`, and your solution is `for for for`, your score is 11 - 9 + 3(6) = 20.

Comment: This is trivial. If a program is just each keyword one time and exactly nothing else, that is a trival score of 0. It's also overly broad, since it doesn't specify what the program must **do**.

Comment: @MyHamDJ This is non-trivial, since few languages can simply paste all the keywords in order and have the program compile.

Comment: I believe the standard is "wikipedia, rosetta code, and/or esolang", why just wikipedia specificially?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I dislike the use of esoteric languages on this site.

Comment: @EMBLEM But they are allowed, and disallowing them is [frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/31716).

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3.4, 110

```
from os import*
def k(z):
 def c():return None;nonlocal z
class F:pass
global b
with open(devnull)as b:
 while b:
  if 1and 0is 0:continue
  elif 1:0
  else:
   for d in[]:yield not d;del d;break
 try:raise 1or False
 except:assert True
 finally:(lambda j:0)
```

Uses every keyword once. Note, in Python 3, `exec` and `print` are functions, not keywords.

Comment: Also, so as to not confuse people from the future, you might want to specify a particular Python 3 version just in case since [`async` and `await` are slated to become keywords in 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 0

```
+-[]><,.
```

Score:

```
l = 8
k = 8
r = 0

l - k + 3r = 0
```

This program takes an input from the user and then prints it.

Comment: This language does not have keywords and is ineligible.

Comment: Depends what you mean by keyword.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I clearly stated that keywords were defined according to the language specification. The word "keyword" appears nowhere on the Wikipedia or Esolangs page.

Comment: @EMBLEM The word "keyword" appears nowhere on *most* Esolangs pages.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That's the idea.

Comment: @EMBLEM But what about the esolangs that have keywords, but don't call their keywords keywords, like Pig?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The Esolangs.org page on Pig calls `PIG` a keyword.

Comment: @EMBLEM Sorry, autocorrect. I meant [Doorspace](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Doorspace).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37361/discussion-between-emblem-and-wizzwizz4).